# FluxCD Kustomize: may not add resource with an already registered id

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kustomize

I have an air-gapped cluster deployed with FluxCD for GitOps. Due to the air-gap I'm rendering Helm charts using `helm template ...`. One of them ([WikiJS](https://js.wiki/)) doesn't contain any way to override the startup command, which is necessary because data is stored on an SMB share (I'm using [csi-driver-smb](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-smb)) and the database (PostgresQL; included in the Helm chart) expects the data folder to be chowned to either 0700 or 0600. SMB has no understanding of *NIX permissions.

To tackle this issue I've tried to patch the rendered Helm chart using a Kustomize file. This results in the following problem on the cluster: `kustomize build failed: accumulating resources: accumulation err='accumulating resources from './apps/wikijs/app/overlays/prod': read /tmp/kustomization-3367117022/clusters/prod/apps/wikijs/app/overlays/prod: is a directory': recursed merging from path '/tmp/kustomization-3367117022/clusters/prod/apps/wikijs/app/overlays/prod': may not add resource with an already registered id: Namespace.v1.[noGrp]/wikijs.[noNs]`.

I understand that this tells me that a resource already exists but I can assure that there absolutely nothing, nada, niente. There is no namespace called `wikijs` and the rendered template doesn't contain duplicate resources.

As already briefly explained I have tried - in order to keep my git repo "reproduceable" - to patch the rendered Helm chart using a Kustomize file. In my dev-environment this renders fine but FluxCD has problems doing the same. I've discovered through some other post that it doesn't just `kubectl kustomize <path/to/kustomization.yaml>` but rather goes `kubectl kustomize --load-restrictor=LoadRestrictionsNone <path/to/kustomization.yaml> | kubectl apply --server-side --dry-run=server -f-` (like explained [here](https://fluxcd.io/flux/faq/#what-is-the-behavior-of-kustomize-used-by-flux)) but that doesn't make any difference.

My directory structure looks like the following:

```
clusters/prod/apps/wikijs/app
|- ks.yml
|- base
|  |- helm_template.yml
|  |- kustomization.yml
|  |- namespace.yml
|  |- values.yml
|
|- overlays/prod
   |- kustomization.yml
   |- patch.yml
```

`ks.yml`

```
---
apiVersion: kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1
kind: Kustomization
metadata:
  name: wikijs
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  interval: 1m0s
  path: ./clusters/prod/apps/wikijs/app/overlays/prod
  prune: true
  sourceRef:
    kind: GitRepository
    name: flux-system
```

`base/helm_template.yml` 
Generate using: `helm template wikijs requarks/wiki --namespace wikijs --values values.yml > helm_template.yml`

`base/kustomization.yml` 
Just a kustomization that includes the resources `namespace.yml` and `helm_template.yml`

`base/namespace.yml` 
Duh, a namespace...

`base/values.yml`

```
image:
  repository: internal.registry/requarks/wiki

ingress:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "prod"
  hosts:
    - host: wiki.somedomain
      paths:
        - path: "/"
          pathType: Prefix
  tls:
    - secretName: wikijs-ingress-tls
      hosts:
        - wiki.somedomain

postgresql:
  persistence:
    storageClass: smb
```

`overlays/prod/kustomization.yml`

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- ../../base

patchesJson6902:
- target:
    group: apps
    version: v1
    kind: StatefulSet
    name: wikijs-postgresql
  path: patch.yml
```

`patch.yml`

```
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/command
  value:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      mkdir -p /bitnami/postgresql/data
      chmod 700 /bitnami/postgresql/data
      find /bitnami/postgresql -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 1 -not -name ".snapshot" -not -name "lost+found" | \
       xargs chown -R 1001:1001
      /entrypoint.sh
```

I really hope it's just a dumb mistake. TIA